# Not clear on why my function is returning none

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have very limited coding background except for some Ruby, so if there's a better way of doing this, please let me know!

Essentially I have a .txt file full of words. I want to import the .txt file and turn it into a list. Then, I want to take the first item in the list, assign it to a variable, and use that variable in an external request that sends off to get the definition of the word. The definition is returned, and tucked into a different .txt file. Once that's done, I want the code to grab the next item in the list and do it all again until the list is exhausted.

Below is my code in progress to give an idea of where I'm at. I'm still trying to figure out how to iterate through the list correctly, and I'm having a hard time interpreting the documentation.

Sorry in advance if this was already asked! I searched, but couldn't find anything that specifically answered my issue.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_definition(x):

    url = 'http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/Default.aspx?action=define&dict=wn&query={0}'.format(x)
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    return soup.find('pre', text=True)[0]

lines = []
with open('vocab.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]

definitions = []
for line in lines:
    definitions.append(get_definition(line))

out_str = '\n'.join(definitions)
with open('definitions.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(out_str)
```

the problem I'm having is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WIP.py", line 20, in <module>
    definitions.append(get_definition(line))
  File "WIP.py", line 11, in get_definition
    return soup.find('pre', text=True)[0]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 0
```

I understand that `soup.find('pre', text=True)` is returning `None`, but not why or how to fix it.

Comment: check if it returns `None`, and if it does, don't try to index into it.

Comment: about the "why": I'd guess because it couldn't find what you wanted it to.

Comment: nonchip - how do I check it what it returns?

Comment: erm… so you're telling me you "understand it's returning `None`" except neither the traceback you've shown says so nor you know if it is?

Comment: @Josh - store the output of the call like `find_results = soup.find('pre', text=True)`, and then check that to see if it's `None`.

Comment: also, usually, the magic you're looking for is called `if` ;)

Comment: In conjunction with what has been said, if you can't find the <pre> element you're looking for try just displaying the results to the screen, using something like soup.prettify('UTF-8') .  Sometimes the web server will return something other than what you expected, especially if you make many requests in a short period of time.

Comment: you might want to edit your question to clarify you have actually no hint at it really returning `None`, and also the title to clarify it's not actually "your function", cause that's misleading (and would be really weird if your own function would return stuff you didn't make it do)

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that `find()` returns a single result not a list. The result is a dict-like object so it tries to find the key `0` which it cannot.

just remove the `[0]` and you should be fine

Also `soup.find(...)` is not returning `None`. It is returning an answer! If it were returning `None` you would get the error

```
NoneType has no attribute __getitem__
```

[Beautiful soup documentation for find()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)